# Using Xebium to Write Tests for Internet Explorer 9

Tags: selenium, fitnesse

I am trying to learn to write tests in xebium for internet explorer 9. I can get it to work in firefox but not IE.

On Xebium's section titled: "Use Custom Web Driver Supplier" (.../ProjectXebium.PoweruserConfigurationSuite.UseCustomWebDriverSupplier)
, it suggests that all I have to do is change the browser name to "iexplore" and it should work. This is what I tried:

!| script | default web driver supplier |                 <-- line 1
| set browser | iexplore |
| $webDriver= | newWebDriver |

| script | selenium driver fixture |
| start browser | iexplore | on url | http://en.wikipedia.org/ |
| do | open | on | /wiki/Hello_world_program |
| check | is | assertTitle | Hello world program - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia |
| stop browser |                                           <-- line 10

When I run it, it gives me exceptions on line 3, 6-10 (5 exceptions total). When I click "Output Captured", it shows me what looks like my classpath. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Make sure you set the zoom level to 100%, and follow all steps under "Required Configurations".